# Confusion about vector spaces and subspaces

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

I am aware that every vector space with a nonzero vector has at least two distinct subspaces (the subspace containing the zero vector and the subspace containing the vector space itself), but I would like clarification on what I think is a contradiction.

Let V describe the vector space {0, 5}. Let W and X describe the subsets {0} and {0, 5}. By the theorem mentioned above, W is a valid subspace, which makes sense because the zero vector is closed under addition and scalar multiplication. However, what does not make sense to me is how X can be consisdered a subspace if it is not closed under multiplication (for example, 2*5 = 10 and 10 is not in the subset {0, 5}).

Am I missing something?

Comment: By what means is $\{0,5\}$ supposed to be a vector space? Id est: over which field and wit which operations?

Comment: This is hard to follow.  You start by saying that $\{0,5\}$ is a vector space, and then you say it is not.

Comment: $V$ is not a vector space (with $\mathbb{R}$ or $\mathbb{C}$ as the field), no matter how you define the operation. Any non-trivial vector space has at least as many elements as in the field.

Comment: @ShiyuLiang Ah ok that makes sense, but what do you mean by "as many elements of the field?"

Comment: @hyponova Sorry for the typos. Say you have non-zero element $x$ and field you are working with is $\mathbb{R}$, then for any two real numbers $a$ and $b$, $ax$ and $bx$ should be different, unless $a=b$. You can prove this by playing around the $8$ or $10$ conditions a vector space satisfies, and any non-zero element in a field is invertible. (any non-zero real has a reciprocal)